# Do-while continue only when number is entered

Tags: c#, console-application, do-while

```
do
{
    try
    {
        a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hodnota není číslo");
    }
} while (a != 'number');
```

I need to end the loop when a number is finally entered and I don't know how. Any help? I am new with this.

Comment: and you don't get any compiler error on `while (a != 'number')` ?

Comment: @Habib He does, but he doesn't know what should be there.  He's asking how to answer the question of whether or not `a` is a valid number.  It's not an ideal question, but it does get his intent off.  I would consider it useful pseudocode in that regard.

Answer (score 9):

Use `TryParse` instead of `Convert.ToDouble` if you have a string that may or may not be a valid double.  You can then use the result of that method call (which is a boolean indicating whether it was successfully parsed) in your loop:

```
double d;
while (!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out d))
{
    Console.WriteLine("The number was invalid");
}
```

Comment: +1 TryParse is better than using the try/catch blocks from the OPs code.

Answer (score 2):

Make "a" a nullable double by declaring at as `double?` and initialize to null. Then just end the loop when "a" is not null.

Comment: The other answer is the "right" way to do this. My answer is intended to show how to make it work while still using "Parse".